# Create symlink tree in existing directories

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, symlink

I carry all of my music around on a 1TB USB drive and have a udev rule to symlink it to `$HOME/Music/` when I plug it in to one of my laptops, which it does.

The issue I have is that this works fine where the directory does *not* exist on the laptop, but it doesn't create the requisite tree where there is a pre-existing directory of the same name (Artist/Album/*.flac) on the laptop.

The script I currently run is this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# repopulate music links when drive plugged in

shopt -s nullglob
export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/jason/.Xauthority

music=(/media/Apollo/Music/*)

find /home/jason/Music -type l -exec rm {} \;
for dirs in "${music[@]}"; do
  ln -s "$dirs" /home/jason/Music/ 2>/dev/null
done
status1=$?

mpc update &>/dev/null

status2=$?
if [[ "$status1" -eq 0 && "$status2" -eq 0 ]]; then
  printf "%s\n" "Music directory updated" | dzen2 -p 3
fi
```

How can I ensure that where a directory exisits on both the laptop and the USB drive, but the contents are slightly different, the files are correctly symlinked? For example:

*USB drive*:

```
Music -- Matthew Shipp -- Patoral Composure -- Track 1
                                            -- Track 2 etc...
                       -- Strata            -- Track 1
                                            -- Track 2 etc...
                       -- Equilibrium       -- Track 1
                                            -- Track 2 etc...
```

*Laptop*:

```
Music -- Matthew Shipp -- Patoral Composure -- Track 1
                                            -- Track 2 etc...
```

In this case, no symlinks to the albums Strata or Equilibrium will be created, presumably because the parent directory (Matthew Shipp) exists.

I would prefer not to use `rsync` to copy the actual data across as I have limited space on the laptops and with `mpd` able to follow symlinks, I have no need to copy the files across.

Is it possible to tweak my script to propagate symlinks into pre-exisiting directories on the laptop?

Comment: Care to use union mounts, for example [via `overlayfs`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/109413/how-do-i-use-overlayfs)?

Comment: @muru I had not considered it. If you think it would fulfill my use case, please write up an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your primary aim is to have a combined view of your local and external Music folder, I think a union mount [via `overlayfs`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109413/how-do-i-use-overlayfs) could be used, especially if the files are not being written to.

The basic command is, in older kernel versions (<3.18):

```
mount -t overlayfs -o lowerdir=/read/only/directory,upperdir=/writeable/directory overlayfs /mount/point
```

For example:

```
$ ls Documents
374620-63301.pdf        My Kindle Content   scan0005.jpg
BPMN2_0_Poster_EN.pdf   scan0003.jpg        StrongDC++
$ ls devel
cse           ossec     ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64-ssh.iso
nexus         scripts   zsh-syntax-highlighting
$ sudo mount -t overlayfs -o lowerdir=$PWD/Documents,upperdir=$PWD/devel overlayfs ~/Documents
$ ls Documents
374620-63301.pdf        scan0003.jpg           
BPMN2_0_Poster_EN.pdf   scan0005.jpg    
cse                     scripts
My Kindle Content       StrongDC++
nexus                   ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64-ssh.iso
ossec                   zsh-syntax-highlighting
```

One drawback is the need for `sudo`, which can perhaps be taken care of using a careful `NOPASSWD` rule.

---

In light of [Jason's blog post](http://jasonwryan.com/blog/2015/01/19/overlayfs/), the mount command for newer kernels changes to using `overlay` as the filesystem, instead of `overlayfs`, and using an additional `workdir`. [The kernel documentation](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt) now codifies this:

> At mount time, the two directories given as mount options "lowerdir"
>   and "upperdir" are combined into a merged directory:
>
> ```
> mount -t overlay overlay -olowerdir=/lower,upperdir=/upper,\
>   workdir=/work /merged
> ```
>
> The "workdir" needs to be an empty directory on the same filesystem as
>   upperdir.

Comment: That worked great: with a few caveats. On Arch Linux, the module and filesystem is just called `overlay` and it also requires `workdir` to be specified (on the same filesystem as `upperdir`). I won't accept this yet as I'd like to see if there are other solutions. Thank you, though.

Comment: @jasonwryan Possibly the effect a newer kernel? I tested this out on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Yes: this is on 3.18.2-2.

Comment: any insight into why it's necessary to specify `workdir` in more recent kernels? the kernel docs only say `The "workdir" needs to be an empty directory on the same filesystem as upperdir.` there's no mention of what `workdir` is for or why it's necessary to provide it.

Comment: @jayhendren From [the post](http://lwn.net/Articles/600106/) that added this option: "Work directory is used to prepare files
   before atomically swithing with destination and needs to be on the same
   filesystem as upperdir."

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [gnu stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/), a symlink farm manager.

Assume the following layout:

```
.
├── drive
│   ├── a
│   │   ├── b
│   │   │   └── bar
│   │   └── c
│   │       └── baz
│   └── b
└── music
    └── a
        └── b
            └── foo
```

Execute: `$ stow --target music --dir drive .`

Result:

```
.
├── drive
│   ├── a
│   │   ├── b
│   │   │   └── bar
│   │   └── c
│   │       └── baz
│   └── b
└── music
    ├── a
    │   ├── b
    │   │   ├── bar -> ../../../drive/a/b/bar
    │   │   └── foo
    │   └── c -> ../../drive/a/c
    └── b -> ../drive/b
```

Comment: Thanks: that is something I had not considered.

Comment: Note that stow is not designed for this use-case and that apparently means overwriting *and discarding* the content of existing files in the way is *not* possible.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Xorg's `lndir`:

```
lndir source target
```

Note that [the source needs to be *relative to the target*](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xutils-dev/+bug/1555055). If you were in a directory with `music` and `drive`, that'd mean:

```
lndir ../drive music
```

Because `drive` is at `../drive` if you were in `music`.